# Running total - trigger or query?

Tags: sql, t-sql, database-performance

Which of the following scenarios will a) provide better performance and b) be more reliable/accurate. I've simplified the process and tables used. I would provide code/working but it's fairly simple stuff. I'm using MS-SQL2008 but I would assume the question is platform independent.

**1)** An item is removed from stock (the stock item has a unique ID), a trigger is fired which updates [tblSold], if the ID doesn't exist it creates a record and adds a value of 1, if it does exist it adds 1 to the current value. The details of the sale are recorded elsewhere.

- When stock availability is requested its calculated from this table based on the item ID.

**2)** When stock availability is requested it simply sums the quantity in [tblSales] based on the ID.

Stock availability will be heavily requested and for obvious reasons can't ever be wrong.

Comment: A trigger spreads the computational load out over time as updates are made, allowing for fast reads. Summing puts the burden on the reader to calculate the result they need. A trigger is more likely to get out of synchronization with reality, but a periodic scan of the tables can fix things up. And physical inventory _always_ gets of of synchronization with databases.

Comment: What is the future of the data? If you will be summing over 15 years of data to determine today's available widgets then you may have an issue. Will you purge old data while preserving checkpoints, e.g. the year-end inventory? Will you move old data to a history table?

Comment: Reports will need to be run over large time periods but not very often, I'm also not concerned with the length of time these queries take to run. The bulk of the checking will be over a maximum period of 6 months.

Comment: As I asked Liath below - one of my concerns is running this query over and over when the result is the same. Will these automatically be cached/optimised or is there a way to cache them?

Comment: Caching won't occur beyond the likelihood of the table data still being in memory buffers, thus reducing disk reads. You could play a shell game of explicitly maintaining an inventory cache table with rows being invalidated by a trigger on sales, but then you're right back where you started with a slightly stranger solution. In some applications it is acceptable to have slightly stale data, e.g. if a cached value is less than 5 minutes old it is good enough for an "In Stock" status on a catalog page. When a user selects a specific item then calculate the stock and update the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to play devil's to advocate the previous answer and suggest using a query - here are my reasons.

- SQL is designed for reads, a well maintained database will have no problem with hundreds of millions of rows of data. **If your data is well indexed and maintained** performance shouldn't be an issue.
- Triggers can be hard to trace, they're a little less explicit and update information in the background - if you forget about them they can be a nightmare. A minor point but one which has annoyed me many times in the past!
- The most important point, if you use a query (assuming it's right) your data can never get out of sync and can be regenerated easily. A running count would make this very difficult.

Ultimately this is a design decision which everyone will have a different view on. At the end of the day it will come down to your preferences and design.

Comment: I'll have to join two tables in order to sum the totals which will increase the query overhead - one of my concerns is running this query over and over when the result is the same. Will these automatically be cached or is there a way to cache them?

Comment: A join isn't a major worry, how many rows and hits per minute are we talking about here? You could certainly store the value in a Totals column/table somewhere if you're really that worried! Beware of optimising before there's an issue - keep it simple if you can

Comment: Worst case scenario 10,000 requests for this query in a minute, but this is only at exceptional peak times. I think you might be right and I'm trying to optimise before finding a problem. I'd like to go about this from a best practices approach though.

Comment: That is quite heavy usage - I'd implement it the simple way first and optimise if required. Make sure you use parameterised queries to give the query plan caching a chance!

Answer (score 1):

I would go with first approach, there is no reason to count rows, when you can have just read one value from database, trigger would not do any bad, because you will not be selling items so often as you request quantity.